# Does the Flash have super strength?

Tags: dc, comics, dc-extended-universe, the-flash, powers

Very simple question, does the Flash (Barry Allen) have superhuman strength?

The reason I ask, and just as one example of him appearing to be very strong, is when he pushes the truck to save the villagers in *Justice League* (2017).

In my eyes, it would take a very strong person to do what he does, such as push a truck that weighs that much as fast as he can run. **OR** , is it the case that he is actually slowed down when pushing the truck, and the fact that he moves so fast means that we as the audience can't tell that he isn't running at full speed?

What I am trying to say is, that it is all relative. When a normal person pushes a truck, they do so at a slow speed and is very noticeable, but because the Flash uses the Speed Force, it seems really fast to us, when in reality, he is going really slow in comparison to his normal speed, like a normal human does. So he is in fact not using super strength , just the Speed Force?

Or, does the Speed Force give him super strength?

I am not sure how the Speed Force works in cases like this, but any clarification would be great.

I would prefer it if there were an answer for the DC Extended Universe, but if not, a canon answer on whether the Flash has super strength.

Answer (score 8):

The Flash does not have super-strength - his only power is his super-speed, and the many (MANY) implementations that ability has.

He's been able to use his speed in ways that could be said to *approximate* super-strength. The [Infinite Mass Punch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IpTwsJaLvA4) is a good example - he accelerates to (near) light speed, giving the punch incredible force due to its relativistic mass.

In the case of the scene in the film, he's pushing a truck in neutral, which isn't that hard. He applies force to the truck via great speed - it may take longer to get moving, but once it gets started, can could get it going at a good clip.

To summarize, he can apply a great deal more speed to a force equation, resulting in a great deal of force.

Answer (score 1):

From the clip you shared, it does not require a whole lot of strength to move a car with parking brakes disengaged. 
It would take a little while to get it to speed but that's it.
His super speed just make the work faster.

Actually stopping the truck without tearing its tailgate is more difficult but let's stay he stopped it from the front and went back to the back to make sure the girl is okay. :)

Comment: Whilst this is well reasoned it would be better if you could tailor it back to the question. i.e. does he have super strength or not?

Comment: Unfortnuately, I can only answer based on the clip you showed and my knowledge in broken down cars ! :)
I cannot prove he doesn't have it, just that it was not required in this precise instance. Now that you point it out, my answer is kinda useless, sorry about that !

Comment: Just a note that I am not the OP. Also this answer isn't useless it does address the question from its premise but it is more of a partial answer than a complete one.

Answer (score 1):

Force = Mass.Acceleration (Isaac Newton's Second Law of Motion). Therefore, when the Flash is running at his incredible speeds he would therefore increase the force of his punch for example. During these times it would have to be said that he has super strength.
In your video clip it looks like he just starts pushing it normally, and the strength is increased exponentially as he begins to accelerate.

Answer (score 0):

There is a scene in *Zack Snyder's Justice League*, where the Flash saves a girl in a car accident then comes to a screeching halt that destroys his shoes and the pavement under his feet. I would think he would have to have some kind of strength / ability, beyond just being fast, to be able to do that and not hurt himself in any way.

Comment: I agree.  The incredible inertial forces The Flash would experience would require him to be physically enhanced in some way.  His high-speed punches would pulverize normal human bones.  That doesn't necessarily mean that he could lift a huge weight above his head, but "Strength" would become an uncertain topic when discussing such a person, one needing a higher level of constraint.